# Why is tkinter <Enter> and <Leave> event not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, events

I am trying to get my widget to light up when the mouse is hovering over it. Here is what I have tried:

```
self.buttons = []
self.buttonTips = ["Select and Add a clip to the project", "Order the clips in your project", "Trim the selected clip",
                   "Cut out audio breaks in the selected clip", "Preview clip (in new window)", "Render/Export your video"]
self.commands = [self.getClipPath, self.reorderClips, self.trimClip, self.cutOutAudio, self._preview, self.finishVideo]
self.images = [_addImage, _switchImage, _trimImage, _autoTrimImage, _previewImage, _exportImage]

for index, tip in enumerate(self.buttonTips):
    self.buttons.append(Button(self.root, image=self.images[index], command=self.commands[index], bg=_bgcolor, relief=FLAT))
    self.buttons[index].photo = self.images[index]
    self.buttons[index].place(x=index * 30, y=490)
    self.buttons[index].bind("<Enter>", func=partial(changeButtonBG, 1, self.buttons[index]))
    self.buttons[index].bind("<Leave>", func=partial(changeButtonBG, 0, self.buttons[index]))

    addToolTip(self.buttons[index], tip)
```

When I change the event type to <Motion> the function runs perfectly, but when I use  or  it doesn't work? Anyone know why?

Comment: I don't understand what "When I change the event type to the function runs perfectly, but when I use or it doesn't work?" means. Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped it - Apparently <> can't go around Motion without with backslahes

Comment: "…, but when I use or it doesn't work?" still doesn't.

Comment: I have now answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have figured out my problem. In this line here:

```
addToolTip(self.buttons[index], tip)
```

the addToolTip() function also adds a bind to the widget. So I edited the binds so they had:

```
button.bind(func=function, add="+")
```

which adding the `add="+"` made it work